# RoR Could not find fog-aws-0.7.0 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I have problem with heroku, when I try to push it, Could not find fog-aws-0.7.0 in any of the sources.

```
remote:        Could not find fog-aws-0.7.0 in any of the sources
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to sample-app-kong.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/sample-app-kong.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/sample-app-kong.git'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Version 0.7.0 of the [fog-aws gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/fog-aws/versions) has been removed from the Rubygems server.

If you run `bundle update fog-aws` in your project folder, bundler will try to load the latest version of the gem instead, and then you'll be able to push to Heroku

Comment: After run it in my project folder, fog-aws using v 0.7.3, i can't push it to heroku, image after run bundle update fog-aws [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9BMS2vkoDwfWlhMa0xSY3p3bjA), and image push to Heroku [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9BMS2vkoDwfRm5BMFBMNTlsTms)

Answer (score 0):

Now I fix it run **git push -f heroku**